# Installing jCycle into Drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, slideshow, libraries, jcycle

I am trying to follow this guide - http://drupalquests.blogspot.com/2012/01/drupal-7-create-slideshow-inside.html - to make a slideshow on my drupal site. It asks for jCycle and after installing libraries and putting the required files in the sites/all/libraries/jquery.cycle i still get a notification saying jCycle is required. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

working fine with :
sites/all/libraries/jquery.cycle/jquery.cycle.all.js

clear cache

Comment: Must have been the naming scheme. I had been clearing cache. Thanks